# Crashing: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I set custom cell imageView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I tried a lot but I am not able to solve it. Following is the code that I have tried. Getting issue at

```
cell.userImageView.image = self.selectedPhotos[0] // Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x1208e5520)
```

Line above are inside

```
func convertAssetsToImage(cell: UserProfilePhotosCell)
```

I use BSImagePicker to pick images from the gallery.
Here is the full code:

```swift
import UIKit
import BSImagePicker
import Photos

class UserProfileVC: BaseCollectionViewController {

    // MARK: Properties
    let userPhotoId = "userPhotoId"

    var SelectedAssets = [PHAsset]()
    var selectedPhotos = [UIImage]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView.register(UserProfilePhotosCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: userPhotoId)

        print("Did load once")
    }

    @objc func showCustomImagePicker(cell1: UserProfilePhotosCell) {
        let imagePicker = ImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.settings.selection.max = 1
        imagePicker.settings.selection.unselectOnReachingMax = true
        imagePicker.settings.fetch.assets.supportedMediaTypes = [.image]
        imagePicker.albumButton.tintColor = UIColor.green
        imagePicker.cancelButton.tintColor = UIColor.red
        imagePicker.doneButton.tintColor = UIColor.purple
        imagePicker.navigationBar.barTintColor = .black
        imagePicker.settings.theme.backgroundColor = .black
        imagePicker.settings.theme.selectionFillColor = UIColor.gray
        imagePicker.settings.theme.selectionStrokeColor = UIColor.yellow
        imagePicker.settings.theme.selectionShadowColor = UIColor.red
        imagePicker.settings.theme.previewTitleAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16),NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        imagePicker.settings.theme.previewSubtitleAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12),NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        imagePicker.settings.theme.albumTitleAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18),NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]

        imagePicker.settings.list.cellsPerRow = {(verticalSize: UIUserInterfaceSizeClass, horizontalSize: UIUserInterfaceSizeClass) -> Int in
            switch (verticalSize, horizontalSize) {
            case (.compact, .regular): // iPhone5-6 portrait
                return 2
            case (.compact, .compact): // iPhone5-6 landscape
                return 2
            case (.regular, .regular): // iPad portrait/landscape
                return 3
            default:
                return 2
            }
        }

        self.presentImagePicker(imagePicker, select: { (asset) in
            print("Selected: \(asset)")
        }, deselect: { (asset) in
            print("Deselected: \(asset)")
        }, cancel: { (assets) in
            print("Canceled with selections: \(assets)")
        }, finish: { (assets) in
            print("Finished with selections: \(assets)")
            print("Count of Assets: \(assets.count)")

            self.SelectedAssets = assets
            self.convertAssetsToImage(cell: cell1)
        })
    }

    func convertAssetsToImage(cell: UserProfilePhotosCell) {
        for asset in SelectedAssets {

            let manager = PHImageManager.default()
            let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
            var thumbnail = UIImage()
            option.isSynchronous = true

            manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 340, height: 365), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info) -> Void in

                thumbnail = result!
            })

            self.selectedPhotos.append(thumbnail)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.userImageView.image = self.selectedPhotos[0]
            print("Dispatch")
        }
    }
}

extension UserProfileVC: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: userPhotoId, for: indexPath) as! UserProfilePhotosCell
        cell.backgroundColor = .yellow
        cell.userImageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showCustomImagePicker(cell1:))))
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return .init(width: view.frame.width, height: 500)
    }
}
```

Custom Cell Code:

```swift
import UIKit
import BSImagePicker
import Photos

class UserProfilePhotosCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var userImageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.image = UIImage(named: "megan")
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        iv.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        iv.constrainHeight(constant: 200)
        iv.backgroundColor = .red
        iv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return iv
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .white
        setupUI()
        print("Did init once")
    }

    fileprivate func setupUI() {
        addSubview(userImageView)

        userImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        // userImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        userImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        userImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true

    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    } 
}
```

I have tried also to pass array with images to UserProfilePhotosCell, and update userImageView.image inside didSet method, no luck, same error.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried to access your array with images inside `cellForRow`?

Comment: I suggest putting a breakpoint on the lane that's crashing and examining variables to see which has the bad address.